# Create a Styled LinearLayout Custom View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view

Imagine you had the following design for a card that you'd be using through an app. A title, button, a divider, and then space for dynamic content indicated by the blue box. We can add anything we'd need inside the blue region but the frame for holding the content would be consistent. For example:

[Card with Placeholder Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsNDf.png)

If I was going to put two `TextView`s inside it might look like this, with the (trimmed down) view layout below:

[Card with Two TextViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejnIh.png)

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:text="My Title" />
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton android:text="ACTION" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="+@id/contentGoesHere">
            <TextView android:text="First element" />
            <TextView android:text="Second element" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Ideally I'd like a custom view so that developers can just do the following and get the consistent stying, or add to the view programatically:

```
<com.customview.CustomView>
    <TextView android:text="First element" />
    <TextView android:text="Second element" />
</com.customview.CustomView>
```

My problem is that just extending `LinearLayout` and making a custom view wont work - it'll create the layout but there's no way to indicate that the inner `LinearLayout` is what I want the views to be added to, so any subviews added in the XML are ignored.

Do I need to make a custom `ViewGroup` and manually inflate the custom holder for the `LinearLayout` (help! onMeasure and onLayout!?) or is there an easier way to make a custom `LinearLayout` view with this styled frame around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that just extending LinearLayout and making a custom
>   view wont work - it'll create the layout but there's no way to
>   indicate that the inner LinearLayout is what I want the views to be
>   added to, so any subviews added in the XML are ignored.

You can manually move the child views into nested `LinearLayout`.

For example:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final ViewGroup container = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.card_layout, this)
                .findViewById(R.id.inner_content_container);
        while (getChildCount() > 1) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);
            removeView(child);
            container.addView(child, child.getLayoutParams());
        }
    }
}
```

**card_layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView android:text="My Title" />
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton android:text="ACTION" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/inner_content_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- content goes here -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

...

```
<com.customview.CustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="First element" />
    <TextView android:text="Second element" />
</com.customview.CustomView>
```

Comment: Interesting! It looks like that method is called in the creation of the view before it starts doing measuring and layout too so it won't mean it's all rendered twice - very nice. I'll give it a go and see how it works for me

Comment: Works quite well, awesome. One thing to note for others is that the final child view of the custom view is the one you inflate in the view class - the `MaterialCardView` in this case - which is why you continue moving the views until the number of children is 1 and you don't move that final view.